# Scala - getting the contents (not address) of another stack

Tags: scala, stack

If I have a stack using the mutable scala stack collection, is there a way I can copy the stack so that I can analyze its elements by popping it without altering the original stack? For instance, suppose I have a stack and code as follows:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack
var stack1 = new Stack[Int]
/** Code that pushes integers on stack1*/
var stackCopy = stack1
while (!stackCopy.isEmpty) {
    println(stackCopy.pop)
}
```

I want to use a while loop to print all elements in stack1. But when I make a copy and pop off that copy, the original stack (i.e. stack1) is also altered. I want to preserve the original stack, so how can I just get the contents, not the address?

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to search for this though since I can't find it in the scala docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use for comprehension:

```
for( i <- stack1 ) { println(i) }
```

or simply call the `foreach` method:

```
stack1 foreach println
```

If you insist using a `while` loop, you can convert it to a list first:

```
var is = stack1.toList
while( is.nonEmpty ) {
  println( is.head )
  is = is.tail
}
```

With all these methods, the original stack will be preserved.